# Bower images integration

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

I use bower and grunt. Grunt scan bower_components and integrate js/css files in special directories. What about relative paths to images in css files? How can I integrate these images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are grunt tasks to build your css and replace image url's with the correct ones:

- [grunt-css-url-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-css-url-replace)
- [grunt-css-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-css-image)